# Unable to create a Twilio sync document from wix backend server

Tags: twilio, velo

update to the earlier question. I am able to create a Twilio Sync document using the below code but Twilio is ignoring the Unique name and data that I am passing along with the API call. Any help would be appreciated.

```
export async function postData() {
  const SID = await getSecret("TwilioSID");
  const token = await getSecret("TwilioAuthToken");  
  const serviceSid = 'ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
  const documentData = {
    'UniqueName': 'my_data',
    'Data': {
          'name': 'Dummy',
          'address': 'My address'
           }
  };
  const auth = btoa(SID + ":" + token);
  const baseUrl = 'https://sync.twilio.com/v1';
  const documentsUrl = `${baseUrl}/Services/${serviceSid}/Documents`;

  const response = await fetch(documentsUrl, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + auth,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(documentData)
}); 
 console.log(response);
 return response.json();
 
}
```

Comment: Update. I am able to now create a document. However, Twilio Sync is ignoring the unique name and data that I am passing along with the create request. Here is the updated code:

Comment: Another update, I am able to send the data if I send it as x-www-form-urlencoded. However, if I set the content type to application/json, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already answered your own question in the comments but I wanted to confirm and summarize for others who might find this question:

This Twilio API requires that you send all data with the content type `x-www-form-urlencoded`. This is also mentioned here in the [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sync/api/document-resource#create-a-document-resource) when you have a look at the **CURL** code sample.

```bash
curl -X POST "https://sync.twilio.com/v1/Services/ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Documents" \
--data-urlencode "UniqueName=user_prefs" \
-u $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
```